# Working with the sum of two independent random variables, and estimating a parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

A network source sends a sequence of zeros and ones, $X_1, X_2, ...$ with $X_i$(iid) Bernoulli with $p = P(X_i = 1), 0 < p < 1$.

Due to disturbances the received sequence is $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ with $Y_i = X_i + U_i$. The $U_i$ are (iid) $N(0, \sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{3}$.

If $Y_i > \frac{1}{2}$ the received value is interpreted as $X_i = 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Ie. the $i$th signal sent if the received signal is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, and $0$ otherwise.

I am trying to -

1. Find $P(Y_i > \frac{1}{2}$ as a function of $p$.
2. Estimate $p$ if $162$ of $424$ observations at the receiver are $1$s and the rest are $0$.

**Attempt**

**1.**

$P(Y > \frac{1}{2})$

$= 1 - P(Y \le \frac{1}{2})$

$= 1 - P(X_i + U_i \le \frac{1}{2})$

$\bigg[X_i + U_i \le \frac{1}{2}$ only when $X_i = 0$ and $U_i \le \frac{1}{2}\bigg]$

$= 1 - P(X_i = 0, U_i \le \frac{1}{2})$

$= 1 - [P(X_i = 0)P(U_i \le \frac{1}{2})]$ as $X_i, U_i$ independent.

$= 1 - [(1 - p)P(\frac{U_i - 0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}})]$

$= 1 - [(1 - p)P(Z \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})]$

$= 1 - [(1 - p)(0.8078)]$

$= 1 - [0.8078 - 0.8078p]$

$0.1922 + 0.8078p$

**Is that correct?**

**2.**

I am really not sure about this part. We have $162$ success from $424$ observations. From part 1. we have that the probability of a success is $\theta = P(Y_i > \frac{1}{2}) = 0.1922 + 0.8078p$. So it seems to me that we are trying to find a maximum likelihood estimate for $p$? It seems we have binomial distribution with $n = 424, x = 162$ and $\theta = 0.1922 + 0.8078p$.

So $L(\theta|162) = {424 \choose 162}\theta^{162}(1-\theta)^{262}$

We can disregard the constant ${424 \choose 162}$ as it won't affect the final answer.

Then $ln [L(\theta|162)] = ln [\theta^{162}(1-\theta)^{262}]$

$= 162 ln(\theta) + 262 ln(1-\theta)$

Differentiating w.r.t. $\theta$ and setting the result = $0$ gives

$\frac{162}{\theta} - \frac{262}{\theta} = 0$

**Obviously something has gone wrong here as this equation is invalid. Is my approach correct? What should I do next?**

Comment: First is not correct: normal variables can easily be negative, so $X+U \leq \frac12$ does not necessarily mean that $X = 0$. Just recall the law of total probability:
$$
  P(X+U \leq \frac12) = P(U\leq \frac12|X = 0)P(X = 0) + P(1+U\leq \frac12|X = 1)P(X = 1)
$$
and use the fact that $U\perp X$. For the second, the MLE method shall work well, just updated $\theta(p)$ based on the correction to the first part. Also, $\log(1-\theta)' = \frac{1}{1-\theta}$ and not $\frac1\theta$ as you have now.